# onClick event on image while already moving

Tags: javascript, image, events, onclick

I'm trying to make an image that moves to the right on my website. When you click the image, it should move to the left. For now, this doesn't happen, any ideas? If possible, in pure Javascript and no Jquery ;)

Also, if you click the image for a second time, it should move to the right again. Every consecutive time, the image should move to the other side. I guess this would be best with a for-loop?

```
<script type"text/javascript">

    window.onload = init;

    var winWidth = window.innerWidth - movingblockobject.scrollWidth;   //get width of window
    var movingblock = null      //object

    movingblock.onclick = moveBlockLeft();

    function init() {
        movingblock = document.getElementById('movingblockobject');     //get object
        movingblock.style.left = '0px';     //initial position
        moveBlockRight();       //start animiation
    }

    function moveBlockRight() {
        if (parseInt(movingblock.style.left) < winWidth) {      // stop function if element touches max window width
            movingblock.style.left = parseInt(movingblock.style.left) + 10 + 'px';      //move right by 10px
            setTimeout(moveBlockRight,20);      //call moveBlockRight in 20 msec
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }   

    function moveBlockLeft () {
        movingblock.style.right = parseInt(movingblock.style.right) + 10 + 'px'
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please first go through the Basics of javascript before trying out something .

> ```js
>     window.onload = init;
>     var winWidth = window.innerWidth;
>     var movingblock = null;
>     var intervalid = null;
>     var isLeft = false;
>
>     function init() {
>       console.log('Init');
>       movingblock = document.getElementById('movingblockobject');
>       movingblock.style.left = '0px';
>       intervalid = setInterval(function() {
>         moveBlock(true);
>       }, 2000);
>       movingblock.onclick = function() {
>         moveBlock(false);
>       };
>     }
>
>     function moveBlock(isSetInterval) {
>       if (!isSetInterval)
>         isLeft = !isLeft;
>       if (parseInt(movingblock.style.left) < winWidth) {
>         if (isLeft)
>           movingblock.style.left = parseInt(movingblock.style.left) - 10 + 'px';
>         else
>           movingblock.style.left = parseInt(movingblock.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
>       } else {
>         movingblock.style.left = '0px';
>       }
>     }
>
>     function moveBlockLeft() {
>       clearInterval(intervalid);
>       movingblock.style.right = parseInt(movingblock.style.right) + 10 + 'px';
>       intervalid = setInterval(moveBlockRight, 20);
>     }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <div id="movingblockobject" style="width:50px;height:50px;border:solid;position: absolute;">
> ```

```
var movingblock = null
```

this are mistakes you have delclared it as null and next line you are binding click event.Also for assigning click event you should assign the name of the function.

```
movingblock.onclick = moveBlockLeft;
```

above is basic bug there are lot like the above.I feel Self learning is much better for basics
try yourself.
try the above it will work but please try yourself

Comment: Thanks, pretty much what I was searching for!

I've only had JS for 1 week in university now, that's probably why I had some basic bugs. Trying my best, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should CSS3 transition, works like a charm. Just toggle a class "right"

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
   <style>
    #movingblockobject{
      width: 40px;
      padding: 10px;

      position: fixed;
      height:10px;


      left:0px;
      -webkit-transition: left 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
      transition: left 2s;
   }
   #movingblockobject.right{
       left:200px;
   }
   </style>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('#movingblockobject').on('click', function (e) {
          $('#movingblockobject').toggleClass("right");
      });
   });

   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="movingblockobject" class="demo">add image here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added a JS fiddle, if you have any more questions feel free to ask. You do need jQuery for that code to work though, including jQuery is fairly easy

Comment: Ah okay. So to make my image move to the left, I basically make two identical functions (left & right) and I use the transition command to switch between the two?
Still, I really want to know how to do it in JS ;)

Comment: If you copy and paste the posted code into a html file it will work